# Parsing dates with JDK 7 u7 and netbeans 7.2 gives unwanted results

Tags: java, parsing, date

Trying this in the title environment:

http://www.javadb.com/check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-date

However, it isn't working in the right way. When `dateFormat.parse(inDate.trim());` is called, it doesn't throws an error, instead it makes a plus one to the date.

For example, if `inDate.trim()` is `"2005-02-29"`, then it makes the parsing like `"2005-03-01"`.

Obviously, I won't this behavior. What can be done?

Comment: there is nothing such as `2005-02-29` the `29th` of february day occurs in `[2000, 2004, 2008, ...]` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_29)

Comment: ...already said on `then it makes the parsing like "2005-03-01"` part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`setLenient()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) method on the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to false to throw errors in such cases:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
sdf.setLenient(false);
System.out.println(sdf.parse("2005-02-29")); // This would throw parse exception.
```

Comment: So damn easy was it huh? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In 2005 february has 28 days. By parsing `"2005-02-29"` there is an offset of one day that turns the date to to march 1st. Use `setLenient(false)` to prevent the parser from "adjusting" invalid dates.

Comment: Already I know that... and I repeat, that's what I wont. Any way to avoid that? And, according to the javadb.com page, it SHOULD throw an ParseException, but it doesn't... I just want some code that says 'hey, this date is not valid!'

Comment: I forgot to add the setLenient method, sorry :). I was searching the correct method definition while editing the post and got sidetracked...